# How to check the length of selected items in for loop using Scriban?

Tags: sxa, scriban

Is there a way to check how many items are **selected** from `Treelist` using Scriban? What I want to do is that if there is only **one item** selected then display something, if there is more than **two** then display also something else. Here is what I have do so far, only with for loop.

```
{{ for i_child_item in (sc_followmany i_item "Items") }}
  /* need to implement logic here */
  <p>Only one item is selected</p>
{{ end }}
```

Now, I know I can maybe use the `if` clause here like I would in any other programming techonology, but I failed to do so since I do not know what is the proper syntax using Scriban.

Comment: @MichaelWest Thank you this helped. My bad for not searching enough. Also I saw on that question that you shared the GitHub repo. Is that repo still valid?

Comment: The official Scriban docs are pretty good references. It's possible the docs reference a newer version of Scriban than what's included in your version of SXA.